# Как вставить данные в БД MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Помогите разобраться.
Хочу вставить данные из формы в 3 связанные таблицы.
в 1 таблице есть 2 поля, куда поставляются id из других таблиц.

```
    $model = $_POST['model'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$name_brigade = $_POST['name_brigade'];

require 'configDB.php';

$sql ="INSERT INTO auto_model(model) VALUES(:model);

INSERT INTO auto(idAutoModel) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID());

INSERT INTO brigade(name_brigade) VALUES(:name_brigade);

INSERT INTO auto(idBrigade) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID());

INSERT INTO auto(number) VALUES(:number)";

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(['model'=> $model, 'name_brigade'=>$name_brigade, 'number'=>$number]);
```

вот то что я написал, но после отправки формы, данные добавляется только в 1 таблицу

Comment: Почему бы вам не сделать три отдельных запроса?

Answer (score -1):

Сделал так. Вдруг кому понадобится.

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO auto_model(model) VALUES(:model);
SET @lastID1 := LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO brigade(nameBrigade) VALUES(:name_brigade);
SET @lastID2 := LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO auto(idAutoModel,idBrigade,number) VALUES(@lastID1,@lastID2,:number)";

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(['model'=> $model, 'name_brigade'=>$name_brigade, 'number'=>$number]);
```